# SQL Server Stored Procedure - Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that returns all rows that are within a given lat/lng and search radius.

When I execute the create code (below) I get:

"Incorrect syntax near '<'"

It must be this line:

```
@p1.STDistance(geography::Point([LATITUDE], [LONGITUDE], 4326)) <= @searchRadius as [DistanceInKilometers]
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks

Here is the entire SPROC:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:         slinky66
-- Create date:    2013-06-26
-- Description:    Returns all meeting locations within a given lat/lng and search radius
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[kiwone_GetNearMeetingLocationInKilometers_SP] 

    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @latitude decimal(18,14),
    @longtitude decimal(18,14),
    @searchRadius decimal (3,2),
    @p1 geography
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

   -- @p1 is the point you want to calculate the distance from which is passed as parameters
   -- declare @p1 geography = geography::Point(@latitude,@longtitude, 4326);

   select
   c.LABEL_NAME,
   k.*,
   @p1.STDistance(geography::Point([LATITUDE], [LONGITUDE], 4326)) <= @searchRadius as [DistanceInKilometers]
   from [USR_KIW_CUS_MEETING] as k
   join CUSTOMER as c
   on c.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID = k.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID
   where c.USR_MEMBERSHIP_STATUS_CODE NOT IN('CR','CSD')
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Geography` and `Geometry` data-types were not in SQL Server 2005.  They were not introduced until SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Thanks - aw shucks. Is there a work around for 2005? Or am I better off doing this in code?

Comment: The only work-around is to upgrade.  And trying to do everything you need in code is going to be challenging to say the least.  It's a lot easier to upgrade.